# An audio jack modem

Tags: audio, adc

I'm looking at controlling Arduino by reading audio commands sent from a raspberry pi (through javascript). I've found the [SoftModem](https://github.com/arms22/SoftModem) code and wonder how it works. It claims that "It uses the phone's audio jack and Bell 202 modem-like FSK encoding", but I wonder how it's done. Doesn't it need to sample the ADC and apply some filtering like FFT? I can't seem to find where all this is done.

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: Which Arduino do you have?

Comment: @NickGammon It's a Nano. I could a Uno though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the blog from the post you linked, he is calculating the frequency received by using the analog comparator built into the processor. That lets you detect a signal rising, falling or both, compared to a reference voltage.

With some interrupts and some timing, you could work out what frequency signal you were receiving, and thus deduce if you got a 0 or 1 bit incoming.

I have a [page about the analog comparator](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11916) if that helps.

Comment: Do you think there should be an opamp in that circuit? Shouldn't there be some kind of "signal conditioning" going on there?

Comment: Possibly. It depends on the voltage levels. The analog comparator is a high impedance input. Maybe a capacitor and/or diode should clamp the input to 0 to 5V.